# Como fazer uma imagem se adaptar ao tamanho da div pelo background-image: url('') usando javascript ou css.

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho uma `div` que tem tamanho 200x300 e uma que tem 50x100, as 2 `div` vão receber o `background-image: url('')` que o usuario informar, porém ele pode colocar uma imagem com tamanho 1280x720, logo, a imagem ficará aparecendo um pequeno pedaço na `div`, como eu poderia redimensiona-la pra caber na div? No caso, em um lugar ter o tamanho de 200x300 e em outro lugar ter o tamanho de 50x100 usando apenas javascript ou CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este seria o caminho mais facil

```css
.place {
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 background-image: url('http://lounge.obviousmag.org/tanto_mar/assets_c/2015/07/Blue-Water-thumb-920x575-115076.jpg');
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="place"></div>
```

Usando npm, tem este pacote aqui: https://www.npmjs.com/package/easyimage

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Eu tenho dificuldades com CSS, coisas que são resolvidas tão simples e eu não descubro. Obrigado Marcelo e aos que responderam!

Comment: Nada cara um prazer

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a propriedade "cover" do css, faça o seguinte, vale lembrar que não é muito aconselhavel usar uma imagem muito grande para algo pequeno

```
<div class="image" ></div>

.image{
background-image: url("seila.png");
background-size:cover;
}
```

Segue exemplo no codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLLMVN